# Can I delete all data/files definitively from my computer?

Tags: data-recovery

I have a couple of very important personal files, that I don't need anymore.

But the problem is that even I delete these files using default Windows 'delete' command, the files can be restored using a simple File Recovery software. So I am delving for a good and efficient way to delete any data permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.pcworld.com/article/209418/how_do_i_permanently_delete_files_from_my_hard_disk.html) articles offers some useful tools. The tools that they recommend are

> [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/)
>
> [SDelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx).

These tools are able to **permanently** delete a file by writing of the file with random data until it can't be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

Look for **File Schredder** programs. There are a lot of them in the web:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/data-destruction/tp/free-file-shredder-software.htm